# How infinite is infinite?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm aware that there are infinite missions. But is there a limit to the number of missions you can take at the same time?

Can you have an infinite number of *active* missions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the nature of Skyrim's infinitely generated quests?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/34890/what-is-the-nature-of-skyrims-infinitely-generated-quests)

Comment: @Bora — I'd tend to disagree.  While I went into detail on how Skyrim's quests work in my answer, the *question* is essentially "How big is the quest log?".

Comment: I was hoping for a discussion on different levels of infinity.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes and no.

Rather than tracking a list of quests you're on, Elder Scrolls games track your progress on *every quest simultaneously*.  If you haven't discovered a quest, you simply have no progress at all.  (And it therefore isn't "active".)

For this reason, there's no specific limit to the number of quests you can be on — you're on all of them at once.  Generated quests (those which are "infinite") simply have your progress reset when you complete them, allowing you to take them again (and because they're random, they're unlikely to be the same twice).

Of course, that means you can only be on one of each generated quest at time; you have to finish the current version before you can start another so that it can be generated anew.  Additionally, some quests have additional restrictions on them, such as a questgiver not handing out more than one generated mission at a time, even if they're of different types.

There isn't even infinite variety in generated quests, as they are "parameterized", meaning that they're in the form of "Steal an <item> from <person>" or "Kill the <group> leader in <dungeon>".  Each parameter can only be selected from a preset list, meaning it's possible to get duplicates.  This is particularly apparent in the Thieves' Guild's bedlam jobs, which appear to only have a single parameter and a very short list (the nine holds).

So while there's no limit like "you can only be on ten", there *are* still limits.

Comment: this is very interesting info on the mechanics behind the Radiant quest system  - do you have an official source for this?

Comment: So one quest from every person in Skyrim, as long as they're different types? This does not bode well for the completionist in me.

Comment: @Alex — No.  This is based primarily on my experience modding prior TES titles, supplemented by the UESP's Skyrim info and my own experiences playing.  It's possible I'm wrong about how generated quests work, but it fits with established TES mechanics and how they've worked for me so far in-game.  I can't be 100% certain until Skyrim's TESCS comes out, but I do have high confidence in everything here.  :-)

Comment: Just a note about infinte quests - they can be the same twice. One of the Bedlam quests I took through the thieves guild had me stealing at least 500 gold worth of property in Riften. A couple turn-ins later and I got the same one.

Comment: @spugsley — Good point.  Generated quests are only as random as their parameters, and the Bedlam quest appears to only have one.