# Are there infinite side-quests in Fallout 4?

Tags: fallout-4

It looks to me like Fallout 4 is Skyrim in a new setting. Skyrim had "[Radiant](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Radiant)" quest engine which [generated](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/34890/what-is-the-nature-of-skyrims-infinitely-generated-quests) infinite side quests.

Does Fallout 4 also use Radiant quest generation - ie infinite quests?

Comment: Infinite would imply procedurally generated quests, which I highly doubt is the case.

Comment: @deutschZuid to be fair, Skyrim, Bethesda's last game, sort of had it (with Radiant Quests).

Comment: @RavenDreamer That was my thinking exactly. It seems like Fallout 4 is rebranded TES 5 and that was released 4 years ago so I would have assumed given the reuse of Creation engine, the Radiant questing would also have been implemented.

Comment: @Coomie It might be worthwhile to add that to your question then. Otherwise it's more of a "How many are there" question, and since it's only been out for [checks watch] 18 hours it's unlikely you'll get an answer.

Comment: I'm assuming miscellaneous quests are probably what you are looking for.  Going to see if the one I got will 'respawn' at some point.

Comment: So far, I've gotten 3 miscellaneous quests from the Wanted! bulletin board in diamond city, one appearing every time I complete the previous one so I think this is a 'radiant' quest souce?

Comment: Funnily I always think of Skyrim as reskinned Fallout 3. :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, it does; I have been doing mission after mission for the Minutemen. They sometime send me back to the same place. Its actually kind of nice.

Comment: note that cleared areas can become "uncleared" again due to these kinds of quests, hence they are infinite

Comment: The Quartermaster quests seem to go on forever, too. I'm actually thinking of exploring as much as possible using this kind of quests instead of discovering locations on my own, is this a good idea? I prefer a sense of purpose when i head out to a specific place instead of roaming randomly. Do they cover a good percentage of all the locations?

Comment: I actually got into an annoying bug with the Quartermaster quests where he would only send me to one settlement regardless of the outcome. The first time I was able to persuade the settlement to give up supplies peacefully, the second time I wasn't able to and had to intimidate them. At that point, I got the quest for a third time, to the same place, but it wouldn't reset. The settlers would only say to go away, so I was unable to complete any more of that quest line.

Answer (score 8):

I've been doing a fair amount of missions for the brotherhood of steel, and it LOOKS infinite ; i've collected something like 20 tech pieces and cleaned about 15 areas for those two NPCs, and it doesn't seem like it's gonna end.

Also, they keep saying " Come back whenever you're ready, I'll always want more tech ", which I assume is a way of telling me its infinite.

So nothing 100% certain, but by the looks of it, there are infinite side quests at least in some cases !

Comment: They are infinite, it's stated in the wiki ;)

Answer (score 1):

Procter teagon keeps sending me to make the NPCs to contribute to the BOS and the caps keep coming so as long as they keep coming I assume there's an infinite amount of quests

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's infinite, I've been doing the Minutemen side quest over and over, I keep going to different settlements and I've reached the point of repetition but it's all good. I collect about 254 xp after the completion of each side quest